# ELMO embeddings

Tags: neural-network, nlp, machine-learning-model, word-embeddings

Could somebody tell me how does elmo work?
Is it good for phrase embedding too?
I m looking for phrase embeddings.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ELMo does not give you sentence-level embeddings, but word-level embeddings.

A sentence-level alternative is [Sentence Transformers](https://www.sbert.net/).